FPGA Fixed Point Arithmetic
I was currently reading this blog (highly recommended) about FPGA doing math (Doing fixed-point Math in FPGA).
But I am having some doubts while reading the second example (named complex_example).
Basically it implements the equation that does the resistance to temperature conversion.
$$ y= 2\cdot 10^{-9} \cdot x^4 - 4\cdot 10^{-7} \cdot x^3 + 0.011 \cdot x^2+ 2.403\cdot x - 251.26$$

My question is more related to the last conversion, op  <=  to_slv(calc(8 downto 0));
Why would the temperature output be 9 bit?
My first thought was because of defining the sign but still in this example sign of the output is not considered since the calc result will be 49 downto -32, I guessed that the author always expects to have a positive output since maybe the equation approximation at that range its like that, then my second question is why would we use signed at all, since also the input is always positive.

If the result could also be negative is it the right solution this code snippet
op <= to_slv( calc ( 49 ) & calc( 7 downto 0 ) );
to preserve the sign?


I am practicing FPGA.

As long as the answer is in range (not outside [-256, +255]), then all of the bits calc(49 downto 8) have the same value — for positive values they're all 0 and for negative values they're all 1. Therefore, it really doesn't matter which one you pick for the sign of your 9-bit output quantity, and calc(8 downto 0) is the simplest choice.

Like the corner cases for this equation would be −251.26 and 1078.60 since x can vary from 0 to 255  , and while your statement is correct about the -251 what about 1078 ( since it needs 11 bits to be expressed and if the 9th bit is a 1 , could it be interpreted as a negative number ?

A 50-bit calc value of 1078 cannot be converted to a 9-bit op value. Are you sure that this is what was intended?

Exactly there is where my confusion comes from ... Since we have an 8 bit input so the max value is 255 ( since its resistance value so only unsigned values ) , inputting 255 to the result the output is 1078 so truncating it in 9 bits ( 1 for the sign i guess ) for sure that we lose information and accuracy ... So in these cases should we just extend the width of the output ? btw thanks for your response since I'm studying FPGA by myself and a feedback especially from experienced engineers like you are really appreciated :D
